"Country X's literacy rate is 5 x higher than the world average" - is Country X included in this average?
This is a concept I have struggled to understand.  Suppose we say:

"Country X's literacy rate is 5x higher than the world average"

Does this mean that Country X included in this average or excluded in the average?
Scenario 1 (NOT in average):
$$\bar{X}_{without} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{n-1}}{n-1}$$
Scenario 2 (IN average):
$$\bar{X}_{with} = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{n-1} + x_n}{n}$$
Does it matter if Country X is an outlier vs not an outlier? Does it the overall distribution of country literacy scores change anything? Is the interpretation different when the country is included in the average vs not included? (e.g. odds vs probability)
Using R, I tried to simulate some literacy scores and see how the country's literacy score changes relative to the population average with/without that country:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(123)

literacy_data <- data.frame(
    country = paste0("country_", 1:100),
    literacy_rate = round(rbeta(100, 2, 2) * 100, 2)
)

total_mean <- mean(literacy_data$literacy_rate)

calc_mean_without_country <- function(data, country_index) {
    mean(data$literacy_rate[-country_index])
}

results <- data.frame(
    country = literacy_data$country,
    literacy_rate = literacy_data$literacy_rate,
    overall_mean = total_mean,
    mean_without_country = sapply(1:100, function(i) calc_mean_without_country(literacy_data, i)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

results <- results %>%
    mutate(
        diff_from_overall = literacy_rate - overall_mean,
        diff_from_mean_without = literacy_rate - mean_without_country,
        abs_max_diff = pmax(abs(diff_from_overall), abs(diff_from_mean_without))
    )

results_ordered <- results %>%
    arrange(desc(abs_max_diff))

top_10 <- head(results_ordered, 10) %>%
    mutate(group = "Top 10 Deviators")

middle_10 <- results_ordered %>%
    slice(45:54) %>%
    mutate(group = "Middle 10")

bottom_10 <- tail(results_ordered, 10) %>%
    mutate(group = "Bottom 10 Deviators")

selected_countries <- bind_rows(top_10, middle_10, bottom_10)

plot_data <- selected_countries %>%
    select(country, diff_from_overall, diff_from_mean_without, group) %>%
    gather(key = "comparison_type", value = "difference", -country, -group)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(y = reorder(country, difference))) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = min(difference), 
                     xend = max(difference),
                     y = country, 
                     yend = country),
                 color = "gray", size = 0.75) +
    geom_point(aes(x = difference, 
                   color = comparison_type),
               size = 3) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue", "orange"),
                       labels = c("Diff from overall mean", 
                                  "Diff from mean without country")) +
    facet_grid(group ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 11),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 9),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "lightgray", color = NA),
        strip.text = element_text(face = "bold")
    ) +
    labs(
        title = "How Countries Deviate from Mean Literacy Rates",
        subtitle = "Comparing deviation patterns across different parts of the distribution",
        x = "Difference from Mean (%)",
        y = NULL
    ) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray50")


So in the end, I guess the difference is minimal whether we include that country in the average or not?

I don't see a math question here.  The English phrase is ambiguous.  The speaker might mean it either way.

@lulu : thank you for your comments ... I was just wondering ... are there any  practical differences in including/excluding that country from the average?

Sure.  If the large number is in the sample then the average goes up which makes yout estimate of the high number go up.

From the phrasing, it should be included, else it will not be the "world's average", and instead will  be the "world without X's average".  (I don't see this as an ambiguous English phrase).

I'm reminded of the song lyrics "Everybody loves my baby, but my baby don't love nobody but me."  which, if we follow the inclusive reading strictly, would have to imply that I am my baby.

Even the "higher" in "5x higher than the world average" is ambiguous: it might be intended to mean "five times the world average" or "six times the world average".  Since the world literacy rate (for adults) is perhaps somewhere near $86%$, neither would be true statements.

This site claims that there are countries with $100%$ literacy rate. That doesn't seem possible. Does that mean that they can tell you what the road signs say?

Perhaps they meant that the illiteracy rate is $\frac 15$ of the average.  At least that is mathematically possible.  But, honestly, the phrase is ambiguous. We could guess and guess, but it is better to just ask whoever said it.

@JohnDouma Per WHO definition, "a person is literate who can with understanding both read and write a short simple statement on his/her everyday life", which is a very low bar and doesn't mean the person has adequate literacy skills. Obviously some people will not meet even that bar, but adult literacy rates around 99% are plausible; a reported rate of 100% probably indicates either excessive rounding or bad data.

In general, Country X would be included in the average, for a couple of pragmatic reasons:
It means that we only need to work with a single "world average" literacy rate, instead of needing to calculate approximately two hundred different "leave-one-out" averages for purposes of comparing every individual country to an average. (And many more if we want to get down to sub-national entities.)
It also avoids various ridiculous/non-intuitive conclusions that might otherwise arise. For instance, suppose our "world" has three countries:

Country A: population 1 billion, literacy rate 50%
Country B: population 10 million, literacy rate 45%
Country C: population 10 million, literacy rate 90%

The average literacy rate over all three countries is 50.3343%. Omitting Country A, it's 67.5%; omitting Country B, it's 50.396%; omitting Country C, it's 49.95%.
Under the alternative interpretation we would be saying that Country A is 17.5% below the average literacy score (50% - 67.5%) whereas Country B is only 5.396% below average (45% vs. 50.396%). But Country B's literacy rate is lower than Country A's!
When we compare to a single world-wide average, a reader can see that "A is 0.33% below average", and B is "5.33% below average", and correctly conclude that B is 5% below A.
In some cases it might not even be possible to perform the "leave-one-out" calculation. For instance, suppose a survey of Australians reports a 99% literacy rate, and a survey of Australians experiencing financial difficulties reports a 98% literacy rate. Without knowing what percentage of Australians experience financial difficulties (as defined by that survey), it would be impossible to remove their contribution from the national rate.
However, one area where we do (kind of) adopt an "average of remaining data points" approach is in statistics, in estimating the standard deviation of a population from the standard deviation of a sample. In this case, we are comparing each sample result to the sample average, usually with the aim of estimating how widely the population is scattered around the true average. In doing this, we need to allow for the fact that the sample result has influenced the average that it's being compared to, so the expected distance between (sample value) and (sample average) will be slightly less than the expected distance between (sample value) and (true population average).
In that application, instead of calculating a separate "leave one out" average for every data point, we compare data points to the all-included average value, and then apply a correction factor which can be determined by the sample size. But the end result is the same as if we'd used the "leave one out" approach.
Edit: The original post has been edited since my response to include an example calculation. The example calculation assumes that "world average" is calculated as a simple unweighted average of the literacy rates of individual countries, which would mean Vatican City (population ~ 500) would have as much influence on the result as China or India (population each ~1.4 billion).
My response assumed a population-weighted calculation, which takes account of the different sizes of different countries in order to estimate the overall ratio of literate people to total people. This would be a better choice for a global measure in most cases.
